# Why Keycloak in Spring Boot allow an (expected unauthorized) user?

Tags: java, spring-boot, keycloak

I'm trying to using Keycloak with Spring Boot and I configured Keycloak with two user: user1 with a role "user" and user2 with a role "not-user".

I expect that when I call the endpoints with user1 everything is fine, while when I call them with user2 the access is denied... but it doesn't happen!!!

Even with user2 I can make calls!

---

This is the log when I make a single call with user2:

```
2020-05-21 10:32:22.483 DEBUG 30380 --- [nio-7771-exec-5] o.k.adapters.PreAuthActionsHandler       : adminRequest http://localhost:7771/contexts/LOCAL/files/upload
2020-05-21 10:32:22.485 DEBUG 30380 --- [nio-7771-exec-5] .k.a.t.AbstractAuthenticatedActionsValve : AuthenticatedActionsValve.invoke /contexts/LOCAL/files/upload
2020-05-21 10:32:22.485 DEBUG 30380 --- [nio-7771-exec-5] o.k.a.AuthenticatedActionsHandler        : AuthenticatedActionsValve.invoke http://localhost:7771/contexts/LOCAL/files/upload
2020-05-21 10:32:22.486 DEBUG 30380 --- [nio-7771-exec-5] o.k.a.AuthenticatedActionsHandler        : Policy enforcement is disabled.
2020-05-21 10:32:22.486 DEBUG 30380 --- [nio-7771-exec-5] o.k.adapters.PreAuthActionsHandler       : adminRequest http://localhost:7771/contexts/LOCAL/files/upload
2020-05-21 10:32:22.487 DEBUG 30380 --- [nio-7771-exec-5] f.KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter : Request is to process authentication
2020-05-21 10:32:22.487 DEBUG 30380 --- [nio-7771-exec-5] f.KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter : Attempting Keycloak authentication
2020-05-21 10:32:22.487 DEBUG 30380 --- [nio-7771-exec-5] o.k.a.BearerTokenRequestAuthenticator    : Found [1] values in authorization header, selecting the first value for Bearer.
2020-05-21 10:32:22.488 DEBUG 30380 --- [nio-7771-exec-5] o.k.a.BearerTokenRequestAuthenticator    : Verifying access_token
2020-05-21 10:32:22.493 DEBUG 30380 --- [nio-7771-exec-5] o.k.a.BearerTokenRequestAuthenticator    : successful authorized
2020-05-21 10:32:22.493 DEBUG 30380 --- [nio-7771-exec-5] a.s.a.SpringSecurityRequestAuthenticator : Completing bearer authentication. Bearer roles: [not-user] 
2020-05-21 10:32:22.493 DEBUG 30380 --- [nio-7771-exec-5] o.k.adapters.RequestAuthenticator        : User 'user2' invoking 'http://localhost:7771/contexts/LOCAL/files/upload' on client 'fs-app'
2020-05-21 10:32:22.494 DEBUG 30380 --- [nio-7771-exec-5] o.k.adapters.RequestAuthenticator        : Bearer AUTHENTICATED
2020-05-21 10:32:22.494 DEBUG 30380 --- [nio-7771-exec-5] f.KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter : Auth outcome: AUTHENTICATED
2020-05-21 10:32:22.494 DEBUG 30380 --- [nio-7771-exec-5] f.KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter : Authentication success using bearer token/basic authentication. Updating SecurityContextHolder to contain: org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.token.KeycloakAuthenticationToken@8e43f478: Principal: user2; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.account.SimpleKeycloakAccount@6489f7f5; Granted Authorities: ROLE_not-user
2020-05-21 10:32:22.494 DEBUG 30380 --- [nio-7771-exec-5] o.k.a.AuthenticatedActionsHandler        : AuthenticatedActionsValve.invoke http://localhost:7771/contexts/LOCAL/files/upload
2020-05-21 10:32:22.494 DEBUG 30380 --- [nio-7771-exec-5] o.k.a.AuthenticatedActionsHandler        : Policy enforcement is disabled.
2020-05-21 10:32:22.495 DEBUG 30380 --- [nio-7771-exec-5] f.KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter : Request is to process authentication
2020-05-21 10:32:22.495 DEBUG 30380 --- [nio-7771-exec-5] f.KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter : Attempting Keycloak authentication
2020-05-21 10:32:22.496 DEBUG 30380 --- [nio-7771-exec-5] o.k.a.BearerTokenRequestAuthenticator    : Found [1] values in authorization header, selecting the first value for Bearer.
2020-05-21 10:32:22.496 DEBUG 30380 --- [nio-7771-exec-5] o.k.a.BearerTokenRequestAuthenticator    : Verifying access_token
2020-05-21 10:32:22.500 DEBUG 30380 --- [nio-7771-exec-5] o.k.a.BearerTokenRequestAuthenticator    : successful authorized
2020-05-21 10:32:22.501 DEBUG 30380 --- [nio-7771-exec-5] a.s.a.SpringSecurityRequestAuthenticator : Completing bearer authentication. Bearer roles: [not-user] 
2020-05-21 10:32:22.501 DEBUG 30380 --- [nio-7771-exec-5] o.k.adapters.RequestAuthenticator        : User 'user2' invoking 'http://localhost:7771/contexts/LOCAL/files/upload' on client 'fs-app'
2020-05-21 10:32:22.501 DEBUG 30380 --- [nio-7771-exec-5] o.k.adapters.RequestAuthenticator        : Bearer AUTHENTICATED
2020-05-21 10:32:22.501 DEBUG 30380 --- [nio-7771-exec-5] f.KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter : Auth outcome: AUTHENTICATED
2020-05-21 10:32:22.502 DEBUG 30380 --- [nio-7771-exec-5] f.KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter : Authentication success using bearer token/basic authentication. Updating SecurityContextHolder to contain: org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.token.KeycloakAuthenticationToken@c999a381: Principal: user2; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.account.SimpleKeycloakAccount@55a7758e; Granted Authorities: ROLE_not-user
2020-05-21 10:32:22.502 DEBUG 30380 --- [nio-7771-exec-5] o.k.adapters.PreAuthActionsHandler       : adminRequest http://localhost:7771/contexts/LOCAL/files/upload
2020-05-21 10:32:22.533  INFO 30380 --- [nio-7771-exec-5] c.s.s.f.c.FileStorageController          : POST request on /contexts/{context}/files/upload
```

---

In my `build.gradle` I've included the dependencies:

```
compile group: 'org.keycloak', name: 'keycloak-spring-boot-starter', version: '10.0.1'
compile group: 'org.keycloak', name: 'keycloak-spring-security-adapter', version: '10.0.1'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
implementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
```

The proerties for Keycloak are:

```
keycloak.auth-server-url=http://localhost:8180/auth
keycloak.realm=SpringBootKeycloak
keycloak.resource=fs-app
#keycloak.use-resource-role-mappings=true
keycloak.public-client=true
keycloak.principal-attribute=preferred_username
```

The Keycloak configuration class is:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = KeycloakSecurityComponents.class)
class SecurityConfig extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        KeycloakAuthenticationProvider keycloakAuthenticationProvider = keycloakAuthenticationProvider();
        keycloakAuthenticationProvider.setGrantedAuthoritiesMapper(new SimpleAuthorityMapper());
        auth.authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    @Bean
    public KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver KeycloakConfigResolver() {
        return new KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver();
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
        return new RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(
                new SessionRegistryImpl());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);
        http
                .csrf().disable()

                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/*")
                .hasRole("user")
                .anyRequest()
                .permitAll();
    }
}
```

What am I missing? Any particular configuration to do for Keycloak?

---

**EDIT:**
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57804416/problem-calling-a-bearer-only-keycloak-endpoint-from-a-springboot-client-app) is a similar problem, but in my case my `SecurityConfig` class isn't ignored!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an **asterisk**!!!

In SecurityConfig class using `.antMatchers("/**")` instead of `.antMatchers("/*")` resolved the issue!

Comment: Good to know ;-) It also seemed strange to me, but I saw it was written the same way in the docs (a bit confusing for an example I guess, but that's the problem of copy&pasteing anyway).

Answer (score 2):

You're using the [Spring Boot adapter](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#_spring_boot_adapter) and that's not the way to secure your web content. You should instead do it by using the Spring Boot configuration:

```
keycloak.securityConstraints[1].authRoles[0] = user
keycloak.securityConstraints[1].securityCollections[0].patterns[0] = /*
```

If you want to use Spring Security which provides much more flexibility, use the [Spring Security adapter](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#_spring_security_adapter) instead (yes, you can use it [even with Spring Boot altogether](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#spring-boot-integration)).

Comment: I followed the documentation and I think that I'm using correctly the [Spring Boot and Spring Security adapters](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#spring-boot-integration). The problem, as you can see from the logs, probably is that `adminRequest` that was done after the authentication and I can't understand why.

Comment: I don't think so.. Why do you use the `keycloak-spring-boot-starter` dependency? That's not told in the docs.

Comment: I followed [this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-keycloak) too and he says: **"There is a Keycloak Spring Security Adapter, and it’s already included in our Spring Boot Keycloak Starter dependency."**.